# Create Software RAID 1 - unexpected failure opening /dev/md0

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I want to create a Software RAID 1 on my Debian. Unfortunately when I execute

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

it returns me

```
mdadm: unexpected failure opening /dev/md0
```

I've also tried `cat /proc/mdstat` but that says `No such file or directory`.

I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the RAID subsystem loaded in to the kernel.

I would suggest you try the `modprobe` and then check what's loaded

```
modprobe raid1
cat /proc/mdstat
```

If you get a result from the `cat` you can retry your `mdadm --create...`

Comment: The  output of `modprobe raid1` FATAL: Module raid1 not found.

Comment: `lsmod ` shows no raid module

Comment: @NRandhawa  is this a standard Debian kernel? Or did you build it yourself?

Comment: yes it is a custom kernel compiled for cubieboard called cubieboard debian server.

Comment: @NRandhawa you're going to need to recompile the kernel with the RAID subsystem configured in. Either built-in or as a module depending on what your machine needs.